# Is this inequality identity correct? $|\sqrt x - \sqrt y| \leq \sqrt{x+y} $

Tags: inequality

Is this inequality correct?

> $$\left|\sqrt x - \sqrt y\right| \leq \sqrt{x+y}$$

Proof:

$$\left(\sqrt x - \sqrt y\right)^2 = x+y-2 \sqrt{xy}
\quad\implies\quad \left(\sqrt x - \sqrt y\right)^2 \leq x+y$$
$(\because  \sqrt{xy} > 0) $

Taking square root on both sides,

$$\left|\sqrt x - \sqrt y\right| \leq \sqrt {x+y}$$

Provided that $x,y \geq 0$.

Comment: Being a little pedantic, taking square roots on both sides would yield $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|\leq\sqrt{x+y}$ (with absolute values on the left), but anyway this is correct.

Comment: If we were on AOPS I would ask to clarify conditions on $x$ and $y$ but nonetheless this is good. Well done!